# Switch progressbar from normal to marquee

Tags: c++, winapi, progress-bar

I have a Dialog that has an progress bar.
I wan't to add a Method to that dialog that sets the progressbar to marquee.
I try following:

```
void CDownloader::SetIntermediate(wstring info)
{
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_DOWNLOADER_LABEL, info.c_str());

    auto style = GetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE);
    style &= ~( PBS_SMOOTH | PBS_SMOOTHREVERSE | PBS_VERTICAL);
    style |= PBS_MARQUEE;
    SetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE, style);

    RECT windowRect;
    GetWindowRect(&windowRect);
    SetWindowPos(HWND_TOP, &windowRect,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

    HWND progress = GetDlgItem(IDC_DOWNLOADER_PROGRESS);
    ::SendMessage(progress, PBM_SETMARQUEE, TRUE, 100);
}
```

However this does not work :(

I set the Window Style to MARQUEE removing styles that may conflict with it, using setWindowPos to update the style and the set the Progress to MARQUEE.

I can set the progress bar in the designer to marquee, but can't switch bac to normal.

Comment: Using SetWindowLong() to change style flags is hit and miss, progressbar in particular does not win any prizes.  The simple workaround is to create *two* of them and make one of them visible based on what you want the user to see.  Or just plain DestroyWindow + CreateWindowEx.

Comment: Then you should write code to turn progress bar into normal. That is remove `PBS_MARQUEE` style, set `PBS_SMOOTH` back and so on.

Comment: You are setting the progress bar styles on the *dialog* instead of the progress bar. It should be `::GetWindowLong(progress, GWL_STYLE)` and `::SetWindowLong(progress, GWL_STYLE, style);`. Also I don't think you need the `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: @zett42 Thank you. I totaly missed this. Now it works.

Comment: @zett42 Yes, he does need `SetWindowPos`, according to Microsoft documentation it says: ***Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using `SetWindowLong` will not take effect until you call the `SetWindowPos` function. Specifically, if you change any of the frame styles, you must call `SetWindowPos` with the `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` flag for the cache to be updated properly***

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know what you mean by "hit and miss", its Microsoft documentation says: ***Calling `SetWindowLong` to set the style on a progressbar will reset its position.*** So they're encouraging `SetWindowLong` usage for that matter.

Comment: Yes, it even says so in the remarks section of [Progress Bar Control Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/progress-bar-control-styles): _"You can set progress bar styles, in the same way as other common controls, with CreateWindowEx, GetWindowLong, or SetWindowLong."_ //// Re `SetWindowPos` / `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`: the condition is _"if you change any of the frame styles"_, but progress bar styles are not frame styles, so that condition doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all that whant the correct code:

```
void CDownloader::SetPending(bool value)
{
    if(value)
    {
        HWND progress = GetDlgItem(IDC_DOWNLOADER_PROGRESS);
        auto style = ::GetWindowLong(progress, GWL_STYLE);
        style |= PBS_MARQUEE;
        ::SetWindowLong(progress, GWL_STYLE, style);
        ::SendMessage(progress, PBM_SETMARQUEE, TRUE,0);
    }
    else
    {
        HWND progress = GetDlgItem(IDC_DOWNLOADER_PROGRESS);
        auto style = ::GetWindowLong(progress, GWL_STYLE);
        style &= ~PBS_MARQUEE;
        ::SetWindowLong(progress, GWL_STYLE, style);
        ::SendMessage(progress, PBM_SETMARQUEE, FALSE,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `SetWindowPos`, according to Microsoft documentation it says: ***Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using `SetWindowLong` will not take effect until you call the `SetWindowPos` function. Specifically, if you change any of the frame styles, you must call `SetWindowPos` with the `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` flag for the cache to be updated properly***